# Different ways of calling an onClick function with navigator.clipboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In each of the following lines of code, I want to copy the url of my website after clicking a button.

Case 1)

```
const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
   if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
     setCurrentUrl(window.location.href)
   }
 }, [])

<button type='button' onClick={() => navigator.clipboard.writeText(currentUrl)}>Copy</button>
```

The code above works fine.

Case 2)

```
const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    setCurrentUrl(window.location.href)
  }
}, []) 

<button type='button' onClick={navigator.clipboard.writeText(currentUrl)}>Copy</button>
```

Why does `ReferenceError: navigator is not defined` occur if I remove `() =>` from the `onClick` ?

Case 3)

```
const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    setCurrentUrl(window.location.href)
  }
}, [])

const shareUrl = () => {
  alert('Copied!')
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(currentUrl)
}

<button type='button' onClick={shareUrl}>Copy</button>
```

Why does the `alert` activate but my url is not copied?

Case 4)

```
const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    setCurrentUrl(window.location.href)
  }
}, [])

const shareUrl = () => {
  alert('Copied!')
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(currentUrl)
}

<button type='button' onClick={() => shareUrl()}>Copy</button>
```

Again why does the `alert` activate but my url is not copied?

Case 5)

```
const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    setCurrentUrl(window.location.href)
  }
}, [])

const shareUrl = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert('Copied!')
  }, 500)
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(currentUrl)
}

<button type='button' onClick={() => shareUrl()}>Copy</button>
```

Why does my url copy after I delay my `alert` activation?

Comment: *ReferenceError: navigator is not defined* should not occur in a browser, I'd think, `window.navigator` exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- case 1: onClick is an event handler and needs a function. This case
  uses a function and this is why it works.
- case 2: This case is not a function.
- case 3: This function contains an asynchronous promise to copy. Not actually copying. You can change the function so that a follow up action occurs after the promise is completed:

  const shareUrl = () => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(currentUrl).then(()=>alert('Copied!'));
  }
- case 4: This function contains an asynchronous promise to copy. Not actually copying. See 3.
- case 5: You give the function time to complete the promise and the promise is fufilled.

Note that the W3C is considering [significant changes to the Clipboard API](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#async-clipboard-api) to handle security issues (amongst other things)

Comment: I tried to implement your recommendation in case 3 with the following:

  `const shareUrl = () => {navigator.clipboard.writeText(currentUrl).then(alert('Copied!')).catch(err =>{console.log('Error:', err)})}`

But I get `Error: DOMException: Document is not focused.`

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Try closing the inspection window and then running it again and then paste the clipboard into a text editor.

Comment: Closed inspect on Google Chrome, and I get the alert message but the URL is not copied.

Comment: This is the entire code that I have working.   function App(){
  
  const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = React.useState('')

  React.useEffect(() => {
   if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
     setCurrentUrl(window.location.href)
   };
 }, [])

  const shareUrl = () => { 
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(currentUrl) 
    .then(alert('Copied!')) 
    .catch(err => { console.log('Error:', err) }) 
  }
  
return (
    <>
    <button type='button' onClick={shareUrl}>Copy</button>
    </>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

Comment: I still get the alert message, but the URL is not copied. (My code is running with other code in production so perhaps something else is causing the error) I will try to find an alternative solution, thank you for your help : )

Comment: Note that due to security considerations, this function only works when served over secured domains (https)